# No symbol table is loaded. Use the "file" command. with eclipse and NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cygwin

I'm trying to debug native android apps using eclipse + NDK + cygwin (obviously on a windows machine)

All seems to work well (after some time of course :) - but I seem to always get the same error when hitting a breakpoint = "No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command."

Even if I use ndk-gdb directly - still same problem.

When I check using "info shared" - I don't my ".o" being loaded.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: u ever figure this out? I was debugging fine and then all the sudden my breakpoints stop working with this error.